# Invalid blog id: For input string

Tags: api, axios, blogger

i am working with  blogger v3 api. and i am trying to make a post request, i have generated the token Oauth.

i added the post data like the docs mentions but when i send the post request i got this error

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid blog id: For input string: \"blogId\"",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid blog id: For input string: \"blogId\"",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "required"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Body

```
{


"kind": "blogger#post",
  "blog": {
    "id": "8692262955862489170",
  },
  "title": "A new post",
  "content": "With <b>exciting</b> content..."
}
```

and this is my code :

```
const axios = require("axios");
require("dotenv").config();




const Imageurl =
"https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b4/f5/11/b4f5111c182daaae4aacfd3b1d5fe340.jpg";
// const data =;

const headers = {
    headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        }
}


async function postData() {
  await axios
    .post("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts/",  {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "blog": {
            "id": process.env.BLOG_ID,
        },
        "title": "rachma 16",
        "content":"hello"
    }, headers)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

postData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you are sending a request to is https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts/
You also need to replace "blogId" in the URL

Correct URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/8692262955862489170/posts/